# Running against localhost, how do i dynamically set a variable based tags from the AWS inventory script

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to modify SSM values using Ansible, the playbook will execute from localhost and the values will be different per environment (e.g. dev, prod, stage). Since I'm using the ec2 plugin, I have the tags at my disposal. However, because I'm executing against localhost, I'm not able to reference the values from group_vars. Now, if I run it from an ec2 host, I have the `tag_env_<ENV>` at my disposal. The problem is I dont want to execute from a remote host, I want to do it from localhost.

```
# group_vars/tag_env_dev
---
db_url: db-instance-for-dev

# group_vars/tag_env_prod
---
db_url: db-instance-for-prod
```